# How to retrieve tag contents as well as following data

Tags: regex, d

I'm trying to create a regex to split shader source code like this:

Source:

```
@shader(vertex):
...shader data...

@shader(fragment):
...shader data...
```

Result:

```
["vertex", "..shader data..", "fragment", "..shader data.."]
```

So far, I've only been able to either isolate the data without the shader type, or I have included the `@shader(` part, but not the type. This is what I've got so far: `@shader\(([^)]*?)\)`. How do I get a splitter to split like that? Thanks.

Comment: Give an examples of shader data. It's pattern might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
@shader\(([^)]*)\):(?:\r?\n)((?:[^@]|@(?!shader))*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/327)